# Should I shuffle the data to train a neural network using backpropagation?

Tags: neural-network, shuffle

I want to train a neural network using backpropagation, and I have a data set like this:

[image]

Should I shuffle the input data?

Comment: The question is clear, just needed some reformatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and it should be shuffled at each iteration, e.g. quote from {1}:

> As for any stochastic gradient descent method (including
>   the mini-batch case), it is important for efficiency of the estimator that each example or minibatch
>   be sampled approximately independently. Because
>   random access to memory (or even worse, to
>   disk) is expensive, a good approximation, called incremental
>   gradient (Bertsekas, 2010), is to visit the
>   examples (or mini-batches) in a fixed order corresponding
>   to their order in memory or disk (repeating
>   the examples in the same order on a second epoch, if
>   we are not in the pure online case where each example
>   is visited only once). In this context, it is safer if
>   the examples or mini-batches are first put in a random
>   order (to make sure this is the case, it could
>   be useful to first shuffle the examples). **Faster convergence
>   has been observed if the order in which the
>   mini-batches are visited is changed for each epoch**,
>   which can be reasonably efficient if the training set
>   holds in computer memory.

{1} Bengio, Yoshua. "[Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533)" Neural Networks: Tricks of the Trade. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 437-478.